# You don’t appear to have an active Azure subscription when creating new Kubernetes service connection in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to create a new **Kubernetes Service Connection** for **Azure DevOps**, but when I try to create it I get the error:

> You don’t appear to have an active Azure subscription

I've tried a few ways to fix the issue but it's not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Here's how I solved it**:

I simply went to **Azure DevOps** > **Project** > **Project settings**

[image]

Next, I went to **Permissions** > **Endpoint Administrators** > **Members**

[image]

Then I added my user to one of the groups under the **Endpoint Administrators** group.
You are also allowed to add your user directly, but permissions are better managed in groups and not individually.

Since the permission updates might take some minutes to take effect in the current web browser window, I logged in to **Azure DevOps** using a **New incognito window** of my web browser, this time I was able to create a new **Kubernetes Service Connection**.

Comment: Add a user into Endpoint Administrators also fix my issue!

Comment: I do not have any **Endpoint Administrators** group by default. I am an admin on my private Azure DevOps (ADO) organization but can not see the Azure Subscription. Note that the ADO was created from Azure Portal.

Answer (score 4):

For me, the problem was that I selected the `Microsoft Account` instead of the `Default directory` Azure Active Directory (AAD) on the Azure DevOps Organizations login page.

[image]

Select the AAD which contains the Azure subscription(s) then you can select them on Azure DevOps.

Answer (score 2):

The root cause of this problem is the directory used by Azure Dev Ops. One of them related to the email and the second one related to the Azure Active directory user.

All you have to do is change the directory to the default one.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YodHw.png)

Comment: After switching to the default directory, it seems you have to create your entire repo and everything again. Is there any other way?