# Unable to see Azure Subscriptions in the Azure DevOps Service Connection

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-subscription

[image]

I'm the owner of my Azure Portal Subscriptions and also my DevOps Portal Organizations also.
But I'm not getting the Azure Subscriptions while creating service connection in Azure DevOps Portal.

I tried Googling and applying some of the steps like

1. checking the access of subscription, app registration,
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/devops/issues-service-connection-task#unable-to-see-the-azure-subscriptions-while-creating-a-service-connection-even-after-having-the-necessary-permissions
3. [You don’t appear to have an active Azure subscription when creating new Kubernetes service connection in Azure DevOps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73316384/22054564)

etc. but no luck

Comment: Check if this [helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76172767/azure-you-don-t-appear-to-have-an-active-azure-subscription-pipeline#comment134335146_76172767)

Comment: Hi @PravallikaKV, Hope you are doing well. Thanks for your response. I tried all the steps present in your given [link](https://blog.georgekosmidis.net/troubleshooting-you-dont-appear-to-have-an-active-azure-subscription.html) but didn't get the subscriptions list while creating the service connection in azure devops project settings.

Comment: Verify if you are in correct directory in [Azure Portal](https://i.imgur.com/Jpftjbj.png). If not, switch to your directory.

Comment: Got it @PravallikaKV, that I switched to default directly by clicking on user account> switch directory in Azure DevOps portal. Then the subscriptions are populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting my comments as answer:

To fix the issue `You don’t appear to have an active Azure subscription` while creating service connections in Azure Devops, troubleshoot using the below steps:

**Check 1:**

- Click on the profile in Azure Devops (or) Portal, Check if you are in your directory which is valid one.
- If not, click on the `Switch Directory`  and Select Default directory.

[image]

**Check 2:**

Security details should be in `disabled` state.

- Go to Portal=>search for Tenant properties=> Manage security details=>check if security details option is `disabled` or not. If this option `Enabled`, change it to `disabled`

[image]

- Then the subscriptions will be listed while creating Service Connections:

[image]

- Make sure your **subscriptions** are **active** in portal:
  [image]